# Problems booting Ubuntu, "gave up waiting for root device"

Tags: boot, grub2, fan

I had very odd things happen after I decided to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 installation to the newer 13.10.

I decided to upgrade version by version to avoid losing my configuration. The upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 brought up the first problems with the graphic drivers. I had to remove the ATI fglrx package to get the x server to work. Then similar issues in 13.04. The worst part was after upgrading to 13.10 when Ubuntu won't load at all. I finally tried to format the partition and make a fresh install, to no avail. At this point even going back to 12.04 won't solve the problem.

Trying to boot in safe mode will bring up the "gave up waiting for boot device" message (I'll attach a photo when I get hold of a PC - I'm on my phone right now).

One very odd thing I noticed is that the computer became extremely noisy, the fan is spinning as if some heavy process was consuming lots of resources, either when on the Live CD or even with just the initial Grub screen. Typing top won't reveal anything.

I can load my Windows 7 installation on another partition just fine, and the fan quiets down in Windows eventually.

I think something may have happened to the MBR, but using the boot-repair package did not fix it.

Any ideas on what might be causing the issue / how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to solve the boot problem creating a boot partition. Why Ubuntu was booting fine beforehand and now it needs a boot partition is beyond my comprehension. Anyway, following the procedure explained in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition I can now boot into Ubuntu 13.10.

The problem with the fan noise is still persisting, and I think is related to the graphics card. I'll keep working on that.

Edit:

This page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver has info on reducing the fan noise. Particularly, on kernel after 3.11.x (as is the case for Ubuntu 13.10) one can modify the following line in /etc/default/grub so it looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=1"
```

Then remember to update Grub: `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Thid does reduce the noise problem, but does not solve it. Even when the computer is idle the fan is still running faster than it used to be. At least now it's bearable.